I want to automate captcha handling during test automation. I want whenever captcha appears it should fill up on it's own
I want to automate captcha handling during test automation. I want whenever captcha appears it should fill up on it's own
I tried tesseract JS to implement OCR but that too doesn't have so much accuracy. So I want something which gives above 80 percent accuracy.

duplicate of https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/17022/how-to-fill-captcha-using-test-automation

duplication of https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/17022/how-to-fill-captcha-using-test-automation
